# Ist es dieselbe Zahl oder die gleiche?

Tags: word-usage, usage, comparison

Wenn ich mich recht entsinne, wird »selbe« dann verwendet, wenn es sich um ein identisches Objekt handelt.

> Dass zwei Personen die *selbe* Hose tragen, wäre also eher unbequem.

»Gleich« sind zwei Objekte, die identische Eigenschaften haben.

> Die *gleiche* Hose können zwei Personen durchaus tragen.

---

Wie verhält es sich nun aber bei »abgeleiteten« Objekten?

> Ich habe eine Postkarte vom Bodensee und du hast eine Postkarte vom Bodensee. Wir stellen fest, dass wir die *gleiche* Karte vom *selben* Motiv gekauft haben.

Auch hier gilt es wieder die Frage zu beantworten: Geht es um dieses eine einzigartige Objekt oder um mehrere Objekte mit identischen Eigenschaften? Deshalb halte ich die obige Variante für richtig.

---

Wie ist vorzugehen, wenn nicht so recht klar ist, ob es sich um ein einziges Objekt handelt oder mehrere? Bei Zahlen fällt mir die Einordnung schwer:

```
2 x 3 = 6
4 x 3 = 12
```

**Werden zwei und vier mit demselben oder mit dem gleichen Faktor multipliziert?**

Drei taucht in beiden Zeilen auf. Man könnte vermuten, es handle sich um mehrere Objekte mit identischen Eigenschaften (in diesem Fall dem Wert der Zahl). Andererseits scheint das Konzept von Zahlen gar keine derartigen »Duplikate« zuzulassen. Die Multiplikation mit drei könnte auch als einzigartige Handlung angesehen werden. So wie du und ich den Bodensee als selbes Urlaubsziel hatten, haben auch zwei und vier denselben Faktor, oder?

Wie kann ich korrekt zum Ausdruck bringen, dass sich identische Zahlen(-werte) wiederholen? Ist dies von Fall zu Fall unterschiedlich und kontextabhängig oder gibt es eine feste Regel?

Comment: Interessante Frage, obgleich ich sie für rein akademisch und praxisfern halte. Meiner Ansicht nach sind „dieselbe“ und „die gleiche“ bei Zahlen synonym. Zumindest, bis ich ein plausibles Gegenbeispiel sehe. Hättest Du eines? Ich denke, jede Zahl ist einzigartig, daher sehe ich keinen Unterschied. Haben Katholiken denselben oder den gleichen Papst?

Comment: @PerlDuck Es gibt verschiedene Möglichkeiten, die natürlichen Zahlen zu konstruieren, z.B. über die Mengenlehre oder als Teilmenge der (ihrerseits wiederum geometrisch hergeleiteten) reellen Zahlen. Die 1 aus der einen Konstruktion ist dann nicht dieselbe wie die 1 aus der anderen, aber es gibt eine Äquivalenzrelation, bezüglich derer sie gleich sind. Aber praktisch ist das völlig irrelevant.

Comment: Tja, mit der Praxisnähe ist es immer so eine Sache. Man könnte auch zu dem Schluss kommen, Futur zwei habe die alleinige praktische Relevanz die Sinnlosigkeit zum Ausdruck zu bringen, die eine Unterweisung in Plusquamperfekt gehabt haben wird, wenn man einmal die Schule verlassen hat. Pragmatisch betrachtet könnte man sich die Unterscheidung zw. selbe/gleiche generell sparen. Andererseits bilden solche subtilen Eigenheiten einer Sprache deren Charme. Nein, ich habe kein Gegenbeispiel und wüsste auch nicht genau wogegen, weil ich in Unklarheit über das alles ja eben diese Frage stelle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I consider this a philosophical question rather than one on German language

Comment: @tofro: I'm certain that my question is not philosophical at all. I want to know what word to use. Period. Plain and simple. I think your intent to close the question implies an answer in itself: that in your opinion there is no clear rule from the language alone and that it depends on the context, which would be a perfectly fine answer I guess. There's nothing philosophical in that either.

Comment: What you're asking for is the main difference between *equality* and *identity*. From the "Hose" example you very well seem to be aware that this is expressed by *gleiche* and *selbe*. That is about all the language has to offer for an answer - Everything else is philosophy. Whether the two numbers "2" in "2+2=4" are equal or identical is a question that can be formed in basically any language.

Comment: @tofro I'm asking for the rules of the language only. "*That is about all the language has to offer for an answer - Everything else is philosophy.*" then please post that as an answer. I'm obviously not aware of all the rules or if my simple understanding of them is correct. I provided the example with "Hose" to point out that the two terms can easily be confused and I could not tell if my case is such a confusion or if the rules themselves don't cover this. Hence my explicit question if this is depending on the context or if there's a rule.

Comment: Hubert has posted that already - And received a +1 for his first sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Soweit es die Sprache betrifft, sind die von dir gegebenen Definition von »das gleiche« und »dasselbe« völlig ausreichend. Offen bleibt aber in der Tat, wann zwei Dinge als identisch angesehen werden sollen. Aber das ist eine Frage, die von der Sprache unabhängig ist. Es ist egal, ob du Latein, Suaheli, Tagalog, Klingonisch oder sonstwas sprichst. Es ist sogar egal, ob du überhaupt sprichst oder schriebst.

Natürlich muss die Sprache überhaupt erst einen Unterschied zwischen »das gleiche« und »dasselbe« machen, damit das Problem eine Möglichkeit hat, sich auch in der Sprache auszuwirken. Aber der Kern des Problems ist von der Sprache unabhängig. Insofern gehört deine Frage eigentlich gar nicht in dieses Forum, sondern vermutlich in ein Philosophie-Forum.

Weil sie aber interessant ist, und eine Auswirkung auf die Sprache hat, halte ich es trotzdem für angebracht sie hier zu behandeln.

Es geht um folgende Fragen:

> - Ist das N in »Ente« dasselbe oder das gleiche N wie in »gehen«?
> - Ist das Elektron, das ein bestimmtes Sauerstoffatom in der linken großen Zehe von Donald Trump umkreist dasselbe Elektron, das ein Eisenatom umkreist, das sich an der Spitze des Eiffelturms befindet? Oder ist es das gleiche?
> - Ist die Drei in ***2 x 3 = 6*** dieselbe oder die gleiche Zahl wie die Drei in ***4 x 3 = 12***?

Das kann man herausfinden, indem man an einer Instanz etwas verändert, und nachsieht, ob das die andere Instanz beeinflusst. Aber genau das hängt nunmal davon ab, was ich verändere.

Ich kann in einem Texteditor das Wort »Ente« schreiben und anschließend den Cursor zwischen »E« und »n« setzen, das »E« weglöschen, stattdessen »gehe« eintippen, dann den Cursor nach rechts bewegen, und »te« weglöschen. Und schon steht das Wort »gehen« da, und es enthält genau das N aus »Ente«. Es ist also dasselbe. Allerdings steht es an einem anderem Ort auf dem Bildschirm. Das N steht sogar ziemlich oft auf meinem Bildschirm, in vielen verschiedenen Wörtern, und ein paar dieser Wörter sind »Ente« und ein paar andere sind »gehen«.

Sind die vielen Versionen von »Ente« in meinem Text dasselbe Wort oder nur das gleiche?

**Die klare Antwort lautet:**

> Es kommt drauf an.

Es kommt nämlich auf den Kontext an, bzw. darauf, worum es in der Fragestellung geht. Wenn es darum geht, die Buchstaben auf einem Plakat mit Farbe auszumalen, dann kann man den verschiedenen Ns durchaus verschiedene Farben und Formen geben. In diesem Sinn sind sie verschieden. Sie sind aber in einem anderen Sinn identisch. Nämlich wenn es um das geht, was ein N zu einem N macht. Wenn es also um das N-sein geht.

Das N ist der 13. Buchstabe im lateinischen Grundalphabet, es ist ein Konsonant, und kommt in deutschen Texten mit einer Häufigkeit von 9,78% vor. Das ist das, was ein N ausmacht. Wenn wir vom 17. Buchstaben reden, reden wir nicht mehr von einem N.

Wenn wir vom N in diesem Sinn reden, dann gibt es nur ein einziges N, und das wird in »Ente« und in »gehen« verwendet. In diesem Sinn ist es dasselbe N.

Dasselbe gilt für die beiden Elektronen. Aus physikalischer Sicht gibt es nur ein Elektron. Es hat eine bestimmte Masse und eine bestimmte Ladung. Wären die Naturgesetze ein wenig anders, dann hätte das Elektron vermutlich andere Werte. Aber auch dann wäre das Elektron durch seine Masse und seine Ladung (und ein paar anderer Größen) bestimmt. In diesem Sinn sind die oben erwähnten Elektronen identisch. Wenn man aber den Aufenthaltsort ins Spiel bringt, und die Elektronen anhand ihres Ortes unterscheidet, ist das wie mit dem N in den beiden Wörtern. In diesem Sinn sind die Elektronen verschieden voneinander.

Und das gilt in gleicher Weise für Zahlen. Die Zahl 3 ist die kleinste ungerade Primzahl, die kleinste Fermat-Zahl, die größte Fibonacci-Zahl, die kleiner als ihr Index ist, und unter den Fibonacci-Zahlen sogar die einzige Primzahl, deren Index nicht prim ist. Die Zahl 3 ist also eine ganz besondere Zahl. Und wenn man in diesem Sinn über die Zahl 3 spricht, ist klar, dass es nur eine einzige Zahl 3 gibt, und wenn sie irgendwo mehrfach vorkommt, dann muss es immer dieselbe Zahl sein.

Aber wenn die beiden Gleichungen auf der Tafel stehen, kann ich die erste Zeile mit gelber Kreide schreiben und die zweite mit blauer. Dann sind die beiden Zahlen verschieden voneinander. Auch wenn ich sie anhand ihrer Position charakterisiere, sind sie verschieden.

Also: Es kommt immer darauf an, in welchem Kontext man von den Dingen spricht.

Comment: Aus dieser Antwort nehme ich mit, dass wohl »selbe« für meinen Fall besser geeignet ist, weil es der identische Ursprung der Zahlen ist, der für mich wichtig ist. Allgemein is es wohl gar nicht unbedingt eine Frage der sprachlichen Korrektheit, wie zB. die Unterscheidung zwischen »dass« und »das«? Würde die Verwendung eines der beiden den Leser dazu bringen zu sagen »Hier müsste aber eigentlich *das andere* stehen.«? Oder wäre das dann Philosophie?

Comment: +1 for the first sentence and the insight that this is what the language covers.

Answer (score 1):

Nach meiner Erfahrung werden die Begriffe ("selbe/gleiche") bei Zahlen in den meisten Fällen synonym gebraucht.

In gewissen Fällen kann es aber Sinn machen hier zu unterscheiden. Neben dem von Matthias genannten Fall aus der Mathematik, fällt mir da zum Beispiel Java (Programmiersprache) ein wo es zwei verschiedene Typen von integer Zahlen gibt: einen primitiven Typ ("int") und einen Objekttypen ("Integer").

Beim "int" gibt es im Prinzip nur eine "3", aber ich kann zwei (oder mehr) verschiedene "Integer" Objekte mit dem Wert 3 haben.